# Python parser returns symbols instead of words from html

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, unicode, cyrillic

Trying to get data from website's html using lxml and XPath. It seems alright except it returns something inappropriate :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://karabas.com')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

test_info = tree.xpath('//div[@class="posters-top"]/a/text()')

print(test_info)
```

This a piece of html:

```
<div class="posters-top">
<a href="https://kiev.karabas.com/didyulya" class="category" style="background-colo #FF7A05;">Концерты</a>
</div>
```

Porgramm returns:

```
[u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u041f\u043e\u044d\u0437\u0438\u044f', u'\u0421\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u0421\u043f\u043e\u0440\u0442', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0443\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043b\u0443\u0431\u044b', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0424\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043b\u0438', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0426\u0438\u0440\u043a', u'\u042d\u043a\u0441\u043a\u0443\u0440\u0441\u0438\u0438', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c', u'\u0421\u0435\u043c\u0438\u043d\u0430\u0440\u044b', u'\u0422\u0435\u0430\u0442\u0440\u044b', u'\u0414\u0435\u0442\u044f\u043c']
```

What is that? Everything seems right, and according  to the amount of those symbols it's somehow code of text. What shall I do with it?

Comment: Would you mind showing us the contents of page before you parse it?

Comment: It's Cyrillic. It displays fine for me in PowerShell.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 what shall I do to see it normally in sublime editor lets say?

Comment: You have `print(test_info)` rather than `print test_info`. Are you working with Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 python 2.7

Answer (score -1):

The data is there - you're seeing the representation of [unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) strings displayed on a terminal that only supports rendering ASCII.

```
>>> print(u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b')
>>> Концерты
```

Here's an example output from Python 2 on my system

```
>>> print u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b'
Концерты
```

I think the issue is that when you `print` a `list` it shows the `repr` of each item in the list:

```
>>> print [u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b']
[u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b']
>>> print u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b'
Концерты
```

If you want to print each item, then iterate through the list and print it directly:

```
>>> items = [u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b', u'8 \u043c\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430', u'\u041a\u043e\u043d\u0446\u0435\u0440\u0442\u044b']
>>> for item in items: print item
... 
Концерты
Концерты
8 марта
Концерты
```

If it's not displaying correctly, check what your stdout encoding is set to

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Comment: And how can I encode in something readable(in this case text is cyrrylic)

Comment: @Vinand where do you want to display the text?

Comment: It's not just the terminal; the code page depends on the version of Python as well. It works as you demonstrate in Python 3, but not in Python 2, which OP is using.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 that statement should work in both Python 2 & 3 if the environment is configured correctly and the terminal supports UTF8 (say). I'll see if I can find a link for troubleshooting